# Electromagnetic wave

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-current, antennas

Light is electromagnetic wave. There is continuous vibration of electric and magnetic field in the light. It means that I I place a conducting coil in the light. There will be change in magnetic flux linked with this loop. Then why is there is no induced current in the loop which is placed in the light?

Comment: Do you mean the photovoltaic effect (which is the same as the photoelectric effect, just employed in a different configuration)?

Comment: If the direction of propagation of the light is into the coil, the magnetic field will never be in the direction of the coil, and thus the magnetic flux through the coil's cross section will always be zero.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: At the light frequency, the skin effect in metals is so strong that metals become dielectrics. In turn, in dielectrics electrons can "vibrate" with the frequency of light without leaving their atoms and molecules. Thus some dielectrics become conductive at these frequencies. This is why glass is transparent to light ("conducts" the lght frequency), but copper is not.

Answer (score 3):

If the loop's axis is parallel to the magnetic field vector in the light, (or, if the light is unpolarised, at any of the directions perpendicular to the propagation direction) then, on the face of it, you're right.

If you were working with radio waves (of wavelength several metres or more) you do get an alternating emf induced in such a coil. Early portable radio receivers of the 1920s often had coils of large cross-sectional area, called 'frame aerials' that captured signals from passing radio waves by means of these induced emfs. [A later version was a coil wound round a ferrite rod.]

However the wavelength of light is far lower, in the order of 500 nm, as you know. This means that a coil won't work in the same way. For one thing, it will 'capture' not the oscillation due to the light at one point, but the oscillations at millions of points, and these oscillations will be at different points in their cycles and won't re-inforce each other. Another effect is that any induced emfs are of such high frequency that free electrons in the coil won't move as you might expect them to do at 'ordinary' frequencies...

Comment: Is it means that visible light can not produce emf  in a conducting loop. But the electromagnetic wave of much higher wavelength than light  can produce emf in the conducting loop. Places anser

Comment: Yes, that's roughly right, though remember that a conducting loop is not a requirement for an emf to be induced; it IS a requirement for the emf to drive a current.

Comment: Is we can induce emf without a conducting loop

Comment: That's right. It's a matter of how emf is defined.

Comment: Please give example where emf is induced without conducting loop

Comment: You move a magnet in empty space in the laboratory. In the laboratory frame of reference there is an emf around any closed loop through which the magnetic flux is changing. Putting it more memorably, you plunge a bar-magnet into a coil that isn't there!

Answer (score 1):

> why there is not current induced in the loop which is placed in the light

There is, or at least can be.  This is exactly how most AM radios pick up the broadcasted signal.

However, the orientation of the coil relative to the propagation direction of the EM wave matters.  The orientation of the coil or antenna relative to the polarization angle of the EM wave also matters.